# What are all the subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}/10\Bbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I thought they would be 
$\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$, where $1 \leq n \leq 10 $.
What is wrong in that ?
And, how is $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ a cyclic group. Is it's generator the element 1 ?

Comment: Also, by Lagrange's Theorem, for any finite group $G$ and subgroup $H \leq G$, the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$. In this case, any subgroup of $\Bbb Z / 10 \Bbb Z$ must have order $1$, $2$, or $5$, or $10$.

Comment: Define $\mathbb Z_n := \mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ for ease of notation and suppose that $\mathbb Z_3$ was a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_{10}$. Then, since subgroups satisfy the axioms of a group, it must be closed under it's operation. But something goes awry!

Comment: @user26857 how are they not a subset of it ?

Comment: @user26857, Lagrange thm. is satisfying, but $Z/3Z$ is cyclic as well and it has all elements that $Z/10Z$ has. Is there any other way of explaining ?

Comment: @bashfuloctopus, what goes awry ? It is closed under addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bijection between subgroups of $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$  and subgroups of $\mathbf Z$ that contain $n\mathbf Z$, i.e. subgroups of $\mathbf Z$ generated by divisors of $n$.

For $n=10$, you get $\mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z$, $\,2\mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z\simeq\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$, $\,5\mathbf Z/10\simeq \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z\,$  and $10\mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z=0$.